# Add multiple users to groups starting with "program"

Tags: powershell

Im trying to add 5 users to 50 AD groups we have. That all starts with program like program_something. How can I do that. I know you can do something like this but Im new with powershell with almost no knowledge so would appreciate help :)

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "program" -Members user1, user2
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by discovering the target groups:

```
$programGroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter 'Name -like "program_*"'
```

Now that you have all the groups stored in a variable, all you need is a loop:

```
foreach($group in $programGroups){
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members user1, user2, user3, user4, user5
}
```